# The app can not be erased in the phone. And generating himself again and again

Tags: android, security, admin

I am just triying to make a security app. And I debug a code on my phone that published on Github. I start the app in my phone. And I guess the app is not working. Because İt is stoped many times. So, I tried to delete it. But When I deleted the app at my phone. It is generating yourself. How can I erase this app?

Also: I can show a video.

https://disk.yandex.com.tr/d/0nhBzbwEcUcx3Q

I publish it a video at my yandex disk.
Also, Here is the sourse code link.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/PasswordEnforcer

How can I fix it? İs it dangerous for my phone's health?